# AngularJS - diretiva e view não estão funcionando corretamente

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-views

Estou fazendo uma pequena aplicação para meu estágio, para estudos e tudo mais, porém mesmo eu seguindo todos os passos, há algo de errado, não consigo fazer com que o angular (versão 1) renderize a view ou a diretiva e nunca retornam um erro.
Já olhei todo o código, porém não consegui reparar em alguma deficiência no que fiz;

Seguem os códigos abaixo:

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br" ng-app="rdi_music">

<head>
<base href="/">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<!-- Carregando CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-overloads.css">

<!--Carregando os scripts-->
<!-- App core -->
<script src="js/core/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/core/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/core/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/core/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/core/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.min.js"></script>

<!-- My Modules -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/index-controller.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/musicas-controller.js"></script>

<!-- My Directives -->
<script src="js/directives/header.js"></script>

<title>Music</title>
</head>

<body>

<header-menu></header-menu>

<div class="container">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**main.js**

```
angular.module('rdi_music', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'musicasController', 
'header'])
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$routeProvider.when('/musicas',{
    templateUrl: 'views/musicas/index.html',
    controller: 'musicasController'
});
});
```

**index-controller.js**

```
angular.module('rdi_music', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('indexController',function($scope){
$scope.isNavCollapsed = true;
$scope.isCollapsed = true;
$scope.isCollapsedHorizontal = true;
});
```

**musicas-controller.js**

```
angular.module('rdi_music', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('musicasController', function($scope){

});
```

**header.js**

```
angular.module('header', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.directive('headerMenu', function(){
var ddo = {
    restrict: "AE",
    templateUrl: "views/directives/header.html"
};

return ddo;
});
```

Comment: `musica-controller.js` deveria ser `musicas-controller.js` não? qual erro acusa no console do DevTools?

Comment: Não, está correto, só aqui no post que errei, já vou editar, mas justamente, não há erro algum.

Comment: algo que pode te ajudar é colocar a palavra `debugger;` no seu js, e abrir o DevTools, ai voce ve o caminho que sua aplicacao esta fazendo. (nao tenho certeza mas acho que a ordem dos arquivos .js influenciam..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltou um pouco de conhecimento sobre como o angularjs funciona na declaração de *Getters* e *Setter* de módulos. Mas você quase chegou lá!

Vamos a uma breve explicação de como esquema de criação de módulos funciona.

**Criando Setter:**

Toda vez que vc declara um módulo você precisa passar a lista de dependências para o ele, mesmo que este não tenha nenhuma dependência externa. Ex:

```
angular.module( 'rdi_music', [] );
```

dentro de "[]" você insere as dependências separadas por vírgula, semelhante como você fez no arquivo **main.js**, mas nesse caso possui um erro, pois você está passando (ou tentando passar) o controller "musicasController" como dependência desse módulo.

O trecho de código correto para o arquivo main.js é o seguinte:

```
angular.module( 'rdi_music', [ 'ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ui.bootstrap', 'header' ] )
  .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider.when('/musicas', {
      templateUrl: 'views/musicas/index.html',
      controller: 'musicasController'
    });
  });
```

**Criando um Getter**

Toda vez que você já tiver um módulo declarado e desejar adicionar funcionalidades ao mesmo, você não deve passar a lista de dependências a este módulo, fazendo isso o angularjs automaticamente entenderá que se trata de um "setter" e não tentará criar um novo módulo.

Sintaxe:

```
angular.module( 'rdi_music' )... // restante do código
```

Então sabendo que já temos o módulo "rdi_music" declarado no arquivo main.js, a sintaxe correta dos arquivos index-controller.js e musicas-controller.js deve ser:

```
angular.module('rdi_music')
  .controller('indexController', function($scope) {
    $scope.isNavCollapsed = true;
    $scope.isCollapsed = true;
    $scope.isCollapsedHorizontal = true;
  });
```

e

```
angular.module('rdi_music')
  .controller('musicasController', function($scope) {

  });
```

**Resumindo o problema:**

Então sabendo como o angularjs funciona nesse aspecto, seu problema era que você declarava o módulo "rdi_music" no arquivo main.js com as dependências (incluindo sua diretiva "header"), logo depois você sobrescrevia esse módulo no arquivo index-controller.js (que nao possuia a injeção da sua diretiva) e logo em seguida sobrescrevia esse módulo novamente no arquivo musicas-controller.js, e como a declaração desse módulo nesse arquivo tinha apenas a injeção de "ui-bootstrap" as outras funcionalidades simplesmente pararam de funcionar.

Criei um [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ucXyWLqeCLvZ6De5995T?p=preview) mais simplificado com seu código, porém funcional para que você entenda o esquema de como os módulos funcionam.

**Referência:**

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module Navegue até a seção "Creation versus Retrieval" o primeiro parágrafo descreve exatamente o seu problema.

> Beware that using angular.module('myModule', []) will create the
>   module myModule **and overwrite any existing module named myModule**. Use
>   angular.module('myModule') to retrieve an existing module.

**Dica final:**

Durante desenvolvimento mantenha sempre a *ferramenta de debug* do navegador aberta (Geralmente ativada pela tecla F12 do teclado) na guia "Console". Caso exista algum erro o angularjs o exibirá ali e inclusive com uma url (gigante diga-se de passagem) para o próprio site do angularjs contendo todos os detalhes sobre o erro apresentado e na maioria dos casos apontando o motivo daquele erro.